# Where can I ask about VPN tools for Windows?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about how to configure a L2TP (a type of connection) with some tools other than Windows' default configurations, or a question about how to configure that type of connection with Windows' default configurations.
On what SE site(s) can I ask about this?

Answer (score 7):

Configuration of software tools, like VPN on Windows, would fit into [Super User](https://superuser.com/). If you needed to ask 'what' tools would work for something, you can try [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).